# Converting minutes to hours (H:mm) in MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to add time given by user in minutes to convert them into h:mm format
The issue is when total time is <=23:59 momentJS gives proper result but if it increases momentJS changes the day and gives wrong result.

For example if I convert `120` min it gives me `2:00`
But in case of `2273` it gives me `13:53`

Here is the code

```
 var totalTimeInMin=2273;
 var totalTimeInHours = moment.utc().startOf('day').add(totalTimeInMin, 'minutes').format('H:mm');
```

Comment: why not use modulo on the total time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just divide by 60 , to get hours and do modulus for minutes

```js
var totalTimeInMin = 2273;
console.log(Math.floor(totalTimeInMin / 60) + ':' + totalTimeInMin % 60)
```

Comment: Only problem is a 60 will return 1:0 rather than 1:00. Change last part to `('00'+(totalTimeInMin  % 60)).slice(-2)`

Answer (score 2):

Posting late, but I think below details are useful here.

[`duration`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) from `momentjs` can also be used for calculating total hours and minutes from a time duration:

```js
function minutes_to_hhmm (numberOfMinutes) {
    //create duration object from moment.duration  
    var duration = moment.duration(numberOfMinutes, 'minutes');
    
    //calculate hours
    var hh = (duration.years()*(365*24)) + (duration.months()*(30*24)) + (duration.days()*24) + (duration.hours());
    
    //get minutes
    var mm = duration.minutes();
    
    //return total time in hh:mm format
    return hh+':'+mm;
}

console.log(minutes_to_hhmm(2273)); // 37:53
console.log(minutes_to_hhmm(220)); //3:40
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

the `function` `minutes_to_hhmm` can be easily adapted to other time durations like - hours, days, months etc based on the [duration constructor in the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)