# NodeJS - How do I convert minutes into hours and minutes format i.e. 4 Hours & 38 Minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, node-modules

I wants to store work Hours in form of Hours and Minutes format i.e. 4 Hours & 38 Minutes.
I have converted into total minutes by subtracting checkIn time and checkOut(current) time. 
Work Hours will be calculated when Employee checkOut.
I am using MongoDB for database.
Let me be more precise, when the employee does the checkout I wants to calculate the total working hours in form of Hour & Minute format

```
attendanceController.js
-----------------------
exports.checkOutAttendance = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const employee = await User.findById(req.user?.id);
const currentDate = format(new Date(), "dd-MM-yyyy");

if (!employee) {
    return next(new AppError("Employee not found or not LoggedIn", 404));
}

const existingAttendance = await Attendance.findOne({
    employee: employee._id,
    date: currentDate
});

if (!existingAttendance || !existingAttendance.checkInTime) {
    return next(new AppError("You have not checkedIn for today", 400));
}

const checkInTime = existingAttendance.checkInTime;
const checkOutTime = Date.now();
const workHoursMillis = checkOutTime - checkInTime;

const totalMinutes = Math.floor(workHoursMillis / (1000 * 60));
// const totalHours = 
const checkedOut = await Attendance.findByIdAndUpdate(existingAttendance._id, {
    checkOutTime: checkOutTime,
    workMinutes: totalMinutes, 
    notes: "CheckedOut Successfully"
});

res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
        data: checkedOut
    }
});
});
```

```
attendanceModel.js
------------------
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const attendanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
employee: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "Employee"
},
date: {
    type: String,
    unique: false
},
checkInTime: {
    type: Date
},
checkOutTime: {
    type: Date
},
workHours: {
    type: Number
},
notes: {
    type: String
}
})

const Attendance = mongoose.model("Attendance", attendanceSchema)
module.exports = Attendance
```

I wants to store the data in form of Hours & Minute format.

Thank you everyone for your time & contribution in advance!!

Comment: *store the data in the form of Hours & Minute format.* You should have two fields to store hours and minutes separately (1). Or you may look to store it as a string format: "HH:mm" (2). It depends on your use case, if just for display approach (2) is simple enough, if may involve updating/calculating the hour/minute, you should look for approach (1).

Comment: You can use Moment Duration  https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format
moment.duration(123, "minutes").format("h:mm");

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert minutes to hours/minutes and add various time values together using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687723/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-minutes-and-add-various-time-values-together-usi), [Converting minutes to hours (H:mm) in MomentJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50001384/8017690)

Comment: @SainPradeep, moment.js is deprecated, you should not use it for new projects.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const attendanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    employee: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Employee"
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        unique: false
    },
    checkInTime: {
        type: Date
    },
    checkOutTime: {
        type: Date
    },
    workHours: { // Stores the total hours
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    workMinutes: { // Stores the leftover minutes after hours are calculated
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    notes: {
        type: String
    }
})

const Attendance = mongoose.model("Attendance", attendanceSchema);
module.exports = Attendance;
```

Modify the Attendance Schema

Update the Checkout Function

```
exports.checkOutAttendance = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const employee = await User.findById(req.user?.id);
    const currentDate = format(new Date(), "dd-MM-yyyy");

    if (!employee) {
        return next(new AppError("Employee not found or not LoggedIn", 404));
    }

    const existingAttendance = await Attendance.findOne({
        employee: employee._id,
        date: currentDate
    });

    if (!existingAttendance || !existingAttendance.checkInTime) {
        return next(new AppError("You have not checkedIn for today", 400));
    }

    const checkInTime = existingAttendance.checkInTime;
    const checkOutTime = Date.now();
    const workHoursMillis = checkOutTime - checkInTime;

    const totalMinutes = Math.floor(workHoursMillis / (1000 * 60));
    const hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60); // Calculate total hours
    const minutes = totalMinutes % 60; // Calculate remaining minutes

    const checkedOut = await Attendance.findByIdAndUpdate(existingAttendance._id, {
        checkOutTime: checkOutTime,
        workHours: hours, 
        workMinutes: minutes, 
        notes: "CheckedOut Successfully"
    }, {new: true}); // Ensure that the updated document is returned

    // Respond with success or further information
    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: {
            attendance: checkedOut
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const totalMinutes = Math.floor(workHoursMillis / (1000 * 60));
const totalHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
const remainingMinutes = totalMinutes % 60;
```

1. Calculate the total minutes worked
2. Divide the total minutes by 60 to get the total hours
3. Calculate the remaining minutes after extracting the hours

Answer (score 0):

As already commented by Yong Shun, you should store the time either as `{hour: 8, minute: 25}` or as ISO string like `"08:25"`

Then I would suggest to use a 3rd party date library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) (deprecated) or [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [day.js](https://day.js.org/). All of them support nicely date math and various output formats. They are much easier to use than the native JavaScript `Date` objects